# I can't properly uninstall Sublime Text on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, uninstallation, package-managers

This is probably a pretty simple problem to fix, but I'm quite new to Linux and certainly Debian so I'm quite lost here. Put quite simply I am trying to remove two different versions of sublime text from a machine running Debian, so I can reinstall just the latest version. This is all on a work computer given to me that I just started using so I'm not sure on past details of how things were installed, etc. Entering the command "sublime" opens sublime build 3083. Build 3114 should also be here but I can't open it. I can't figure out how to remove it because it isn't in apt-cache and when I try apt-get remove for "sublime", "sublime-text", "sublime-text-2", and "sublime-text-3" it can't find any packages under that name. How do I get rid of this thing? Thanks.

NOTE: I check usr/bin and sublime is listed there. So it must have not been installed through the package manager?

Comment: What is the output of `which sublime`? It should point you to where the binary is installed, and thus where you can remove it.

Comment: Ah yes, I left a note as you were commenting this in the main question. Sublime is in usr/bin. Does this mean that it wasn't installed with the package manager?

Comment: Have a look here ;) http://askubuntu.com/a/327752

Comment: Thank you! May I ask what that final command,

sudo sed -i 's/sublime\.desktop/gedit.desktop/g' /usr/share/applications/defaults.list

does?

Comment: I ask because I think I may need to modify something. defaults.list doesn't exits in my applications directory.

Comment: Aha. Don't run that. It replaces - if Sublime was configured as your default editor - Sublime with ... gedit :(

Comment: AH! I see. Well, that did it! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Jethro helped me learn this in the comments to the original question above. Thanks! https://askubuntu.com/a/327752